# evaluating each element on a list by a fuction with range up to its max value

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list such as:

```
list = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
```

and I want to evaluate a functions such as:

```
j = [0]
for i in range (0, 1.5):
    j.append(list + 5)
for i in range (1.5, 3):
    j.append(list + 10)
```

and I did not knew what was wrong with it, because I forgot to iterate which is in fact pretty basic, but I forgot

Comment: So how would you define a function with two different expression, range dependent?

Comment: Well that actually help me remember something, thanks

Comment: "I want to implement a function that uses the 320 values on my list and give me back another list 320 results" I have no idea what this means. Can you show a *complete* example (using small numbers instead of 3800 and 320), that includes the exact input, the exact desired output, the exact actual output, and an explanation of how the output is wrong? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: I hope the edit help you in your future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you appear to start off `j` containing the value `0` when I'm pretty sure you want an empty list, so replace that line with `j = []`. Then, you start iterating over a range as opposed to iterating over the actual list, and adding the whole list to numbers which won't work. I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
my_list = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
j = []
for i in my_list:
    if 0.5 <= i <= 1.5:
        j.append(i + 5)
    elif 1.5 < i <= 3:
        j.append(i + 10)
```

This way the variable `i` is equal to the values from the actual list not from a range, and we use `if` loops to test what value `i` is and determine which function to use

Comment: Is a useful and serious answer, so thanks. I had solve the problem but maybe your way is more elegant. I have an additional question though: when I use j[ ] instead of j[0] it tells me that the index is out of range, I try to "move" it a little but the problem remains... anyways, thanks

Comment: I have an extra question about this: I got an error saying that "indices must be integers or slices, not float". How can I solve that?